# The unknown in the derivative of the function

Tags: calculus

We have function $f(x) = \lfloor x + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor x + x^2 $.

If $ x\to \frac{1}{2}$ then $f'(\frac{1}{2}) = 1$

But If we use the definition this way instead:

---

$\lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}{\frac{f(x) - f(\frac{1}{2})}{x - \frac{1}{2}}} = \lim_{x\to \frac{1}{2}^-}{\frac{x^2 - \frac{3}{4}}{x - \frac{1}{2}}} = \infty $

Which one is true and why? Is it possible to help me?
I am sorry for bad English. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{2}$. Look at its graph and you will see what I mean:

[image]

Your function is discontinuous at this point, and so the rate of change of the function at that point is meaningless, unless you take the *limit* of the rate of change of the function up to that point. If you approach $x=\frac{1}{2}$ from the left, then the graph is basically that of 
$$y=x^2$$
and so the rate of change within the interval $(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ would be
$$y'=2x$$
and the limit of the rate of change as $x\to\frac{1}{2}$ from the *left* would be $1$. But if you approach from the right, you will be focusing on a steeper "segment" of the graph. Within that segment, the graph behaves like
$$y=x^2+x$$
and so the rate of change within the interval $(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2})$ is 
$$y'=2x+1$$
and the limit of the rate of change as $x\to\frac{1}{2}$ from the *right* would be $2$.

The answer is that *neither* of these are really "correct". The function is not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{2}$, so its derivative at that point is meaningless.